# Is it possible to let a user change value of a single field in their account profile without going to the user edit page?

Tags: forms, users

On my site, users have several single-value boolean checkboxes as part of their profiles.

In various places on the site, I want to let users toggle one of these fields on or off without going to the user edit page.

I'm using Panels, so I'd like to somehow embed a way to edit just the value of a single field into a given page/panel.

What I tried:

- Use the Field Permissions module to block access to the field.
- Create a flag with the Flag module.
- Let users flag or unflag themselves.
- Make rules with the Rules module to set the value of the field based on the user flag.

This works, but it's very cumbersome to set up and tricky to maintain.  It also prevents users from editing the value on the user edit page; they have to use the flag instead.  So I'm wondering if there is a more straightforward way to do what I want.

This is similar to [my question from a couple years ago](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50172/is-it-possible-to-make-a-second-edit-account-page-that-only-allows-users-to-ed), but that question is about modifying the user account page.

Comment: Related to https://www.drupal.org/node/1824500 and https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/edit maybe? Just a rough idea, don't know enough about Panels to answer.