# create a custom form based on user fields

Tags: 7, users, forms

I created  new menu item witch I want to insert a custom form to edit some user fields :

```
$items['user/%user/edit-custom'] = array(
  'title' => 'Knowladge',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('user_profile_form_custom', 1),
  'access callback' => 'user_edit_access',
  'access arguments' => array(1),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
return $items;
```

Then the custom function that return the form :

```
function user_profile_form_custom(){
  module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
  
  global $user;  
  $user = user_load($user->uid);

  $form = drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $user, 'account', 'custom'); 

  return $form;
}
```

When visiting `"user/%user/edit-custom"` page I can see the profile page, then with some logic code in `hook_form_alter` I can hide some fields and show up only needed fields...

But the problem that I can't save the form, I get this error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function user_profile_form_validate()
> in path_to_drupal/includes/form.inc on line 1514

this solution is inspired from answers described in [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27335/drupal-7-use-part-of-the-user-profile-form-on-another-page) .

Have you any idea please how to solve this, or if you have another way to get some user fields, edit them in a custom page, and save the changes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you missed the comment (below)? It's on the post you linked to.

> "module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages'); should be added to hook_init() otherwise all profile form functionalities that require AJAX calls will return the error 'Call to undefined function user_profile_form_validate().'"

Comment: yes, I tried also to add "module_load_include" in hook_init but I get another error : Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object in path_to/modules/user/user.pages.inc on line 313

Comment: @Boussettamoez - It's telling you that `$user` is not an object. Did you keep the rest of your code in `user_profile_form_custom()`? I'm not sure if it's related, but you shouldn't have to call `user_load()` after `global $user;`. But I'm not even sure the global user is what you want. Don't you want the user whose ID is in the menu path (%user)?

Comment: @Boussettamoez - In `user_profile_form_custom()`, unless I'm misunderstanding what you are trying to do, I would suggest getting your user this way: `$user = user_load(arg(1));`.

Comment: Sorry, but I get the same error even if I use user_load(arg(1));!

Comment: But you will get the right user. :-) You're right about `$form` and `&$form_state` (below). Amazed that I overlooked that. I believe it's required.

Comment: Please, don't do that. Do you even know that hook_init() is called on every page load!?
Just replace of **module**_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'user', 'user.pages') with **form**_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'user', 'user.pages') and you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the parameters `$form` and `&$form_state` in the custom function must correct the bug!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of module_load_include(), use form_load_include().

Here's the code:

```
global $user;
$account = user_load($user->uid);

$form_state = array();
$form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($account);

form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'user', 'user.pages');

$form = drupal_build_form('user_profile_form', $form_state);

$output = drupal_render($form);

return $output;
```